# Converting Existing site into Mobile Version

Tags: javascript, html, flash, cakephp

The existing site in cakephp with flash. We need to convert it into mobile version.
Please suggest me is there any possibilities for making mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following frameworks:

**For ui and minor ux options**

- iwebkit http://www.iwebkit.info
  (targets both safari and webkit based
  browsers)
- iui http://code.google.com/p/iui/

**For a more advanced ux**

- jqtouch http://ww.jqtouch.com/ (targets safari, but looks quite good on webkit)

My personal favorite is jqtouch, and as you right now I'm in the middle of porting a cake app to mobile browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a real mobile site, you want to look into a framework for that. There are two big ones:

- [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is a site based mobile site, you need to create html in your cakephp views. This is served to the user
- [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) is aimed at more sophisticated sites with a lot of interactions. The site is serves as single page, all necessary data if loaded via json. You mentioned CakePHP, so you might want to use [Bancha](http://banchaproject.org) if you decide to use Sencha Touch.